# Need a regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I am getting a string as output example below,

`"errors": "Report with Report Name production already exists[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@8cb9814"`

I need a regex to identify a pattern to eradicate **`[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@8cb9814`** it from output string. So that the output string looks like

`"errors": "Report with Report Name production already exists."`

Below is the code I am trying to complete.

```
let x = `"errors": "Report with Report Name production already exists[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@8cb9814"`;

console.log(x.replace("Some Pattern", ''));
```

Comment: Use `x = x.replace(/\[Ljava\..+$/, '');`

Comment: It's actually not that hard really. Have you tried doing it yourself? You just need to grab the relevant part and discard the rest. You can try using the "[" as the identifier if the message format is going to be consistent.

Comment: `s.substring(0, s.indexOf('[Ljava'))+'"'`

Comment: Using the example @anubhava provided... https://regexr.com/4iqjm